# Basic Authentication using urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I've been struggling to access a certain webpage and have trouble doing so. Below is the code. Can you tell me what am I missing? Please note that I can access all the links inside the corporate LAN. This is the problem only with the external links. I get a 401 with the WWW-Authenticate key.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -w

import urllib2

myURL = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
username = 'uname'
passwd = 'password'

req = urllib2.Request(myURL)
print req

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    print response.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.headers
    print e.headers.has_key('WWW-Authenticate')
    print e.code
else:
    print "This page is not protected"
    sys.exit(1)

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password('CTTEST', myURL, username, passwd)
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except IOError, e:
    print "Incorrect Credentials"
```

Comment: *I can access all the links inside the corporate LAN.* Any of those links in your LAN is using authentication?

Comment: I didn't have to use authentication within the LAN.